# Failed to instantiate one or more classes in android studio

Tags: java, android, class

I want to integrate **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayou**t. In my android application, I have added below code in my xml file for the Email EditText, for username , for password . I have also added dependencies in build.gradle. Now , its not instantiating the one or more classes result not showing the output activity.

try this:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not find color resource matching value 0x7F06FF0A (resolved name: purple_500) in current configuration.
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1161)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1137)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:1141)
    at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getColorStateList(Resources_Delegate.java:264)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:1126)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$Api23Impl.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:688)
    at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:244)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:519)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:179)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:649)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:446)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:351)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:294)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:359)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:717)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:873)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:192)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you are facing issue. Btw the error say to declare color resource named purple_500 or may be change it where it is used.

Comment: okay sure, I have changed it where I am using it. Now ,it showing output.Thanks for your help.